# How to troubleshoot a plugin that works on web but fails on native Android/iOS?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We have a plugin that was created that works on the web, but fails on native Android/iOS. A screenshot is attached that shows the problem:

[Widget fails to load on native mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4eo6.png)

What configuration should I be looking at to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: It's best to narrow things down by verifying that the mobile device is on the latest version of the app (which is `3.2` as of this writing), ensuring that the mobile device isn't connected to a VPN which may be disrupting connectivity, switching from cellular to Wi-FI (or vice versa), and finally trying to reproduce the problem in the [Simple Plugin Example](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example/).

Comment: You might want to take a look at how the [External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/externalapplications/) is configured, especially around Redirect URIs and how they interact with Content Security Policy (CSP) and/or other [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We found out that the error loading on native mobile was due to some restriction on the user's wifi network. When they switched to cellular the widget was able to load.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! If I may ask, are you able to share what specifically was a restriction in the user's Wi-Fi network? I ask because we have a [Troubleshooting -> Network Connectivity](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/troubleshooting/#network-connectivity) section that we may be able to update to help other developers in the future.